# Using "dynamic/object" data types in action methods for PUT/POST/PATCH using xmlmediatypeformatter

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have the following action methods:

```
  public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, dynamic item)
    {
    }
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(object item)
    {            
    }
    public HttpResponseMessage Patch(intid, dynamic item)
    {            
    }
```

If I POST/PUT/PATCH an item using content type of "application/json", I get a non-null item in the above methods representing the keyvalue pairs of the json payload, however, if I change the content type to "application/xml" and send an XML payload in the body instead of a JSON payload I get a "null" for the item.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it works when you pass JSON is because WebAPI uses JSON.NET as its default JSON serializer. JSON.NET supports dynamic objects.

WebAPI uses the DataContractSerializer for XML serialization by default. Unfortunately it doesn't support dynamic objects. I'm guessing this is causing your issue. The base class library provides another xml serializer called XmlSerializer which can be used with WebAPI too, but it doesn't support dynamic objects either.

Comment: Darn! this is an inconsistent experience from a client perspective

Comment: Looks like this is indeed the case, this throws content negotiation out the door...